# Wordpress Plugin manipulate have_posts()

Tags: plugins, loop, blog

I want to develop a plugin, which changes the post order on the blog page, I think I need to manipulate the `have_posts()` function. How can I do this?

Comment: Look into `pre_get_posts`. The blog page is the home page, so you can use the `is_home()` conditional check to target that specific page. You can also sort the loop with `usort()` and the `the_posts` filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard query for posts uses `orderby => 'post_date'` and `order => 'DESC'`. The best candidate for arbitrary sort of posts would be `orderby => 'menu_order'` and `order => 'ASC'`. The `menu_order` is not generally used for posts but it is safe to be used. As suggested by Pieter Goosen use action hook `pre_get_posts`:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'your_function_name' );
function your_function_name( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'menu_order' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
```

The above is for front end. For back end use visual drag and sort jquery and update the database. You can check the logic in pageMash plugin.

Comment: And if I want to return my custom post order, which can not be ordered by wordpress, should I save the value as a post meta? and order over it?

Comment: No manipulation of post meta is necessary. Every post type including custom post types has `menu_order` field. As long as your query is a main query the code above should work.

Comment: I want to querry by comment count, but later using my own algorithm, if I write the resulting order of my algorithm into menu_order it should work?

Comment: I don't see why not.